# Problem using align in enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

I'm creating a list with enumerate of both positive and negative numbers, and would like the numbers to be lined up with one another, i.e. all in the same column.  I also have a second list with decimal numbers, and I would like to line up the decimal points.  I tried using \begin{align} within the enumerate list as in

```
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{align*}[t]
\item $-&2$
\item $3$
\item $-18$
\item $83.2$
\item $-112.2$
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

but it gives me the error \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.  I have the amsmath package loaded, and I'm compiling with xelatex.

Edit: xelatex is now giving me this error even when I have commented out the problem area.

Comment: try `\begin{aligned}[t]` instead

Comment: I tried that, since I read that that was the correct syntax in math, but it gives me the same error message.

Comment: Why don't you use an `array` environment with the `siunitx` package for alignment?

Comment: Doing it within enumerate seems much simpler than using an whole new package and environment, but I will try it if there is no other option.

Comment: You could try something like this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcounter{tmp}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{>{\stepcounter{tmp}{\thetmp}}lSS[table-format = 3.4]}
& 6 & 2.3456 \& -7 & 34.2345 \& 20 & -6.7835 \& -12 & 90.473 \\end{array}
\]

\end{document}`.

Comment: You are already using the amsmath package for the align environment so why not use that? `align` is a multi-row environment for aligning things which is exactly what you want, you are using separate align environments for each entry which means there is no alignment at all (apart from the syntax error of putting the align environment inside `$..$`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is exactly what I'd like to do.  I would really rather not use new environments if the one I'm already using will suffice.  I have edited my mwe, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You still have align inside math mode, just remove it. Also the `{..}` around each item is not doing anything (`\item` does not take an argument). Why not use one of the posted answers?

Comment: Sorry about the bad syntax, I inherited the latex file and I'm just trying to work through it now.  I edited the mwe to take align out of math mode but I am still getting the same error - is there something I'm misunderstanding?  I would really prefer to use enumerate for the automatic numbering.

Comment: @user27446 why don't you want to use a dedicated package to easily produce alignment at decimal separators? I could give you an option using only `align`, for example, but compared to my answer the code is quite longer.

Comment: @user27446 please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user27446 please also notice that in some of the options in my answer (the ones using `tabular`) the numbering is automatically done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `\item` in math mode, so your construction:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{align*}[t]
\item $-&2$
\item $3$
...
\end{enumerate}
```

will produce errors.

To get the desired arrangement (tabular-like material with enumerated rows and alignment at decimal separator for certain columns), you could use a `tabular` environment; the alignment can be achieved using the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcounter{tmp}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{tmp}\thetmp}lSS[table-format = 3.4]}
& 6 & 2.3456 \\
& -7 & 34.2345 \\
& 20 & -6.7835 \\
& -12 & 90.473 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are two other options: one, using just `align` (from the `amsmath` package) and the other one using a standard `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{tmp}

\begin{document}

\noindent Using \texttt{align*}:
\begin{align*}
1 && 6 && 2.3456 \\
2 && -7 && 34.2345 \\
3 && 20 && -6.7835 \\
4 && -12 && 90.473\phantom{0} \\
5 && 10 && 3.4\phantom{000} 
\end{align*}

\noindent Using \texttt{tabular}:

\setcounter{tmp}{0}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\stepcounter{tmp}\thetmp}lrr@{.}l}
& 6 & 2 &3456 \\
& -7 & 34 & 2345 \\
& 20 & -6 & 7835 \\
& -12 & 90 & 473 \\
& 10 & 3 & 4 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the first solution (using `siunitx`) implies less work.

Comment: I will try using the tabular environment, it does look like the better option.  I appreciate you taking the time to show the differences between the two options.